# I get a ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'f' when running a linear model fit. I converted all the strings already. Why I get this error?

Tags: python, pandas, valueerror, one-hot-encoding

I have a df `combo_df.shape` `(7403, 43)`
I have split the data to numeric and categorical and ran `pd.get_dummies()` on the 'object' dtype data
Later I made sure I converted all the dtypes to numeric. I check with the following code:

```
combo_df_dummy.dtypes.unique()
array([dtype('int64'), dtype('float64')], dtype=object)
```

I made sure there no NAs either

```
np.sum(combo_df_dummy.isnull().any())
0
```

The final shape of the df is `(7403, 148)`

However, when I run the `lm_model.fit()` I keep getting the `ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'f'`.

I checked for 'f' string (as suggested by [@Barmar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1491895/barmar)) in the df columns with no luck. I used:

```
for col in combo_df_dummy.columns:
    if np.sum(combo_df_dummy[col].astype('str').str.find('f')>0)>0:
       print(col)
```

I get nothing back!

What am I missing? I spent way too many hours trying to resolve this issue

Comment: There's a string `f` somewhere in the df.

Comment: @Barmar, I added a update to the question regarding  your comment